# Opera: How can I change the default mail account?

Tags: email, opera

I have added two mail accounts to Opera M2 (10.50). When I hit Compose it uses the mail account that's on the top of the list as default to send from. But I want it the other account to be on the top. How can I change this?

Can't drag the account in the Mail and Chat accounts dialog. Didn't find anything about it in opera:config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a way, but hopefully someone else will have a less hackish way :p

Close Opera and go to the Mail Root Directory of Opera and open up the `accounts.ini` file. There you'll find a section called `[Accounts]` at the top. In there you'll find some lines which reads `AccountX=Y`, where `X` is a sequential number and `Y` is a number corresponding to a belonging `[AccountY]` section. Mine said:

```
Account1=1
Next Available Id=3
Count=2
Account2=2
```

I then just swapped them around so it read:

```
Account1=2
Next Available Id=3
Count=2
Account2=1
```

Open Opera again and the accounts should have been swapped around and what you put as `Account1` should be at the top and used as the default in new emails :)

***Mail Root Directory:*** opera:config#Mail|MailRootDirectory

---

**Update:** Ok, after I did this something weird seemed to happen... could be because I also changed the name of the accounts... anyways, take a backup and be careful if you try this :p I ended up just deleting the whole Mail directory and add the accounts in the right order. Only use IMAP accounts anyways so no risk of losing anything except that I had to download all the headers and such again.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I am also unable to find a setting for that! Suggest you delete and recreate the email accounts in reverse order, so that the desired account is at the top of the list and works as the 'default'.

Comment: Anyone who does this beware - mail for POP accounts can be lost if you delete the account in Opera (if it's only stored locally).

Comment: @Ant: Good point! I only use IMAP though, so not a problem for me :)